# Consuming Kafka fails due to "Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to consume events using Apache Flink. 
The code is very basic, trying to connect the topic split words by space and print it to the console. Kafka version is 0.9.

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaStreaming {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "kafka servers:9092...");
    props.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "kafka servers:2181...");
    props.setProperty("group.id", "flinkPOC");
    FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), props);

    DataStream<String> dataStream = env.addSource(consumer);

    DataStream<String> wordDataStream = dataStream.flatMap(new Splitter());
    wordDataStream.print();
    env.execute("Word Split");

}

public static class Splitter implements FlatMapFunction<String, String> {

    public void flatMap(String sentence, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {

        for (String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
            out.collect(word);
        }
    }

}
}
```

The app does not print anything to the screen (although I produced events to Kafka). I tried to skip the Splitter FlatMap function, but still nothing happens. SSL is not required from Kafka.
When I submitted the job to the cluster I found in the logs timeout exception:

```
2019-08-20 14:36:17,654 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (1/1) (02258a2cafab83afbc0f5650c088da2b) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

I am really not sure what am I doing wrong:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is clearly in the Flink version for Kafka 9 since the same code runs fine when using Kafka 2.
So I am afraid there is no solution for Kafka 09.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error that simply tells you that your client has failed to properly connect to the Kafka cluster. Do you know if the cluster has authentication enabled? Can you connect to the cluster with the `kafka-topics` script using the same `zookeeper` property?

I would also use the `kafka-console-producer` and `kafka-console-consumer` scripts that come with Kafka from the Flink host to ensure basic functionality.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response. 
I can consume events by using the built in kafka script kafka-console-consumer.sh.

Comment: And I also disabled authentication from Kafka side.

Comment: I tried to run the same code but this time using Kafka 2 and FlinkKafkaConsumer011 and it work fine.
I suspect that the problem is specific for the kafka 0.9 connector.

Comment: Ah that'd do it, a Kafka 0.9 consumer is very old, and likely didn't support the authentication mechanism your cluster has enabled.